# Python bind Dataclass and TypedDict (Inherit Dataclass from TypedDict)

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, typeddict

I want to bind somehow my TypedDict (which I'm using for database results type hints) and my Dataclass.
I'm not that it may be hard to implement and TypedDict is just a dict in run-time, but anyway.
Logically, in point of design and architecture, it sounds sensible, more consistent, and neat.
Well, the implementation should not affect the Design.

```
from typing import TypedDict
from dataclasses import dataclass

class UserDB(TypedDict):
    id: int


# Causing error ValueError: no signature found for builtin type <class 'dict'>
@dataclass
class UserDC(UserDB):
    # "id: int" should be inherited from `TypedDict`
    name: str

# Or at least I want:
@dataclass
class AnotherUserDC:
    db_data: UserDB
```

Expected:
The field `UserDC.id` (at least type hint) should be inherited from `TypedDict`
Actual:
`ValueError: no signature found for builtin type <class 'dict'>`

Answer (score 3):

A  `typing.TypedDict` is something fundamentally different from a dataclass - to start, at runtime, it does absolutely nothing, and behaves just as a plain dictionary (but provide the metainformation used to create it).

It will accept unknown fields and not-valid types, it works only with the item getting `[ ]`  syntax, and not with the dotted attribute syntax, etc...

So, the easier thing to do is to inject the meta-information of your typedicts into the dataclass metainformation, *Before*  running the dataclass decorator.

If you don't need the inheritance relationship - i.e., your code will not at any moment ask if an UserDC object is an instance of UserDB, that will work.

To make it, a short intermediary decorator will do the job:

```
def inject_fields(parent):
    def doit(cls):
        cls.__annotations__ = parent.__annotations__ | cls.__annotations__
        return cls
    return doit


# and then:


class UserDB(TypedDict):
    id: int

@dataclass
@injectfields(UserDB)
class UserDC:
    # "id: int" is injected from `TypedDict`
    name: str
```

Now, if you will need the OOP inheritance relationship - i.e. `isinstance(UserDC(...), UserDB)` is expected to return `True`, I first beg you to review your modelling: it makes little to no sense, as I stated in the start of the answer: in Python one dictionary is a thing, a dataclass is another.

If you were dealing with any other types than TypedDict, and still you get to this point, due to whatever reason in your specific setup (say, UserDB comes from a project created by another team), Python would offers the "virtual subclassing" workaround: when classes can answer of subclasses of others without any "physical" inheritance relationship.
But typing.TypedDict in particular goes out of this way to ensure even this way is blocked. It is *really* meant to be a static-typechecking only thing, and not to be used at runtime for nothing else than as a plain dicitionary.

Check the related snippet in`typing.py`, the sourcecode of the typing module:

```
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, other):
        # Typed dicts are only for static structural subtyping.
        raise TypeError('TypedDict does not support instance and class checks')
```

Comment: Thanks, a cool answer one.
My only goal - is to preserve OOP logic. 
I'm don't this indeed in the code.
I'm a bit frustrated that python has so many workarounds for a single word `struct`.
`dataclass`, `typeddict`, `named tuple`, etc.